# How to Do Custom Fields to Output a Definition List

Tags: posts, custom-field, customization

So, I'd like to add some custom write panels when you go to write a new post in the WP admin.  I'd like it to have a heading for each, and then a text input field where I can write in some text.  I would need it to be inserted into the single.php file, and then output as a definition list.  So, each custom field heading would be a pre-determined , like "Materials Needed" (without the quotes...), and then whatever I put within the blank text field would spit out as a .

Here's an example of what it would need to output as...

```
<dl>
<dt>Purpose of Activity</dt>
<dd>To improve the skill to strike an object with a paddle.</dd>
<dt>Prerequisites</dt>
<dd>practice of striking skills - focusing on the following cue words: 
<ul>
<li>Flat Paddle</li>
<li>Stiff Wrist (pretend it is in a cast)</li>
<li>Watch the Object</li>
</ul></dd>
<dt>Suggested Grade Levels</dt>
<dd>K-2</dd>
<dt>Materials Needed</dt>
<dd>one paddle for each student, 2-4 folding mats, 50+ balloons</dd>
<dt>Description of Idea</dt>
<dd>Use paddles and balloons in self-space prior to this activity. Practice the underhand hit (with the face of the paddle to the ceiling). The class is divided into six teams of "farmers" scattered around the room. Each team will have their own "barn" made of two folding mats standing upright and forming a barn-like structure. Fifty plus (50+) balloons will be scattered on the gym floor. On the "go" signal, students use their paddle to round up the farm animals (balloons) and herd them into their barn. Only one balloon can be taken at a time. Once a student has a balloon, other students are not allowed to touch that particular balloon. The game continues until all balloons are in the barn. Students then return to their starting positions and sit with their paddles at rest.</dd>
<dt>Variations</dt>
<dd>Use koosh balls, a shuttlecock, a foam ball, a dead tennis ball</dd>
<dt>Teaching Suggestions</dt>
<dd>To apply math skill integration, balloons can be worth various points and students can add the points at the end of each round.</dd>
<dt>Adaptations for Students with Disabilities</dt>
<dd>larger/lighter paddle, balloon tied to chair for continuous hitting</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Metabox Script for WordPress has been of great help to me: http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/p/meta-box-script-for-wordpress.html
You will be able to ouput all that you shown above and more too. Completely customizable to your wishes.